# How to fix Flutter MaterialApp(not_enough_required_arguments)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

when returning MaterialApp flutter shows error as follow "error: 1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found. (not_enough_required_arguments at [demo] lib/main.dart:9)"[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jviQ.jpg)

```
const _categoryName = "Cake";
const _categoryIcon = Icons.cake;
const _categoryColor = Colors.green;


import 'package:solution_02_category_widget/category.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(UnitConverterApp());
}

class UnitConverterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Unit Converter',
  home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        body: Center(
          child: Category(
            name: _categoryName,
            color: _categoryColor,
            iconLocation: _categoryIcon,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It'll be better to paste your code here, than add screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the title argument under AppBar Widget. You can in turn wrap the appBar argument inside the Scaffold.  The scaffold is like an empty page that gives your app the white background. Below is a sample code implementation:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // debugShowMaterialGrid: true,
      theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness .light,
          accentColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Some text'),
          ),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the appbar, I am building a layout without appbar in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine without error if i remove the Category() widget. The below code is working fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const _categoryName = "Cake";
const _categoryIcon = Icons.cake;
const _categoryColor = Colors.green;

void main() {
  runApp(UnitConverterApp());
}

class UnitConverterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Unit Converter',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        body: Center(
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe the problem is in the Category() widget so if you post it i can check it for you.

Comment: but I get the same error with unchanged new flutter projects.

Comment: Stop the emulator, run Flutter Clean then try to rebuild the app